# How cypress test buttons click trigger modal

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a layout with many blocks. Each block has a hamberger menu button can trigger the menu open. The class is `burger-menu-button`. In each menu, there is a button, text is 'remove' and class is 'burger-menu-remove-btn'. When click the remove button, it will trigger a modal with class 'modal-confirm'.

I'm writing a script to trigger all blocks remove. I use `.each` to run each one and trigger the click, but when my second burger menu open, it will block the first one modal open. So I can only get the last one removed.

My script is:

```
cy.get("body").then((body) => {
    cy.get(".burger-menu").each((menu) => {
        cy.get(menu).within((menuIn) => {
            cy.get("burger-menu-button")
                .click()
                .then(() => {
                    const menuItemRemove = menuIn.find(".burger-menu-remove-btn")
                    if (menuItemRemove) {
                        menuItemRemove.trigger("click")
                        const modalConfirmBtn = body.find("button:contains('confirm')")
                        if (modalConfirmBtn) {
                            modalConfirmBtn.trigger("click")
                        }
                    }
                })
        })
    })
})
```

Since for my hamber menu and modal, when I click outside of the element, it will hide. With my script running, it's like it cannot run one by one, they're running at the same time, so some clicks will affect the modal and burger menu open and I can only remove the last one.

How can I ensure it run one by one so once one is removed, it runs another. The click between won't affect each others.

Answer (score 1):

When using a loop in a Cypress test you need to **throttle the test code** if using actions like clicking open a menu or clicking to dismiss a modal.

This is so that one iteration of the loop will not over-run the next one.

#### Throttling

I've added a couple of commands that will throttle the code, i.e wait until a condition on the page has been met.

They are only examples, since I don't know the full application.

```js
cy.get('.burger-menu').each((menu) => {

  cy.wrap(menu).within((menuIn) => {
    cy.get('burger-menu-button').click()

    // 1st waiting point - menu items should be visible
    cy.get('.burger-menu-item').should('be.visible')

    cy.get('.burger-menu-remove-btn').click()

    cy.contains('button', 'confirm').click()

    // 2nd waiting point
    cy.get('.modal').should('not.be.visible')
  })
})
```

#### Conditionals

I notice you have a couple if `jQuery` + `if()` which make me think that not all burger-menus have the button.

Please note, `if()` statements can put a spanner in the works when they follow an action.

For example `menuItemRemove = menuIn.find(".burger-menu-remove-btn")` in your code, if the preceding `click()` causes the page to change, you have no insurance the the test will find the `.burger-menu-remove-btn` on first try.

Using a command `cy.get('.burger-menu-remove-btn')` gives you insurance, because it retries - but you **must** know that the menu has the button, else the test fails.

To do that, you would select only menus that have the button, for example

```js
cy.get('.burger-menu:has(.burger-menu-remove-btn)').each((menu) => {
  // only process the menus with a remove button
```

Refs: [jQuery has-selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector)